# Laravel 5.3 :class Http\Controllers\Route' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to print the `current` route in my controller

```
 namespace findetrip\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        /**
         * Show the application dashboard.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index($page = 'home')
        {
            echo $route = Route::current();
            return view('admin.'.$page,['pageName'=>$page]);
        }

    }
```

But I got the following error:

> Class 'findetrip\Http\Controllers\Route' not found

I found many questions similar to this issue, but didn't get a proper solution.

Comment: Is this a class or just a function?

Comment: @KhorneHoly its a class

Comment: You are trying to access class `Route` but you have not included it in your namespace, so your script can't find it. Either use full url or include the namespace. PS: An IDE like PhpStorm will do this for you automatically.

Comment: `\Route` if you don't want to add use (it will use facade from alias), if you would call something dynamic on some Route instance, you would want to instead add use `use Illuminate\Routing\Route;`

Answer (score 9):

To use **Route::current()**, you have to use Route like:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

**Note:**
Look at your `app.php`, you should have this on `'aliases'` array:

```
'Route' => "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route",
```

Comment: Got this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::current()` but this import `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;` works fine

Comment: @BlessanKurien That just means, that your class `Route` has no method `current`. You might have included the wrong Route class

Answer (score 2):

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
```

Use these code in the below of your controller and try it.

Answer (score 1):

To use ***Route::current()***, you have to include Route class in your controller:

```
use Route;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the `Route` facade isn't imported inside your code. You need to import it by using the following statement:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Comment: Would you like to explain your answer? It helps newbie to better understand

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).